# How to run IDE Fix Pack for XE7

Tags: ide, delphi-xe7, pack

I need to Know How to run IDE Fix Pack for XE7,
I installed the IDE fix Pack but i need to know how to import it inside XE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to do. You install it, and that's it. To check that it has installed correctly select the *Help | About* menu action, and look in the *Installed Products* list box. If IDE Fix Pack has been successfully installed, it will be listed there.